# Getting "Capability matching failed at NIC." error while trying to set a custom profile - NativeWiFi + WinXP SP3

Tags: c++, profile, zeroconf, windows-xp-sp3, wifimanager

I am trying to create an ZeroConfig client to connect my Atheros WiFi device to an AP (for learning purpose). I am using NativeWiFi (WinXP SP3) to query my device & set a profile against the device so that it can connect to an AP. The steps I have taken follows like this -

1. get NativeWiFi handle by calling openHandle.
2. Enumerate the device list & Get a GUID of the device.
3. Scan & Retrieve a list of available network.
4. Trying to set a autoconnect profile with WlanSetProfile()

I am getting "Capability matching failed at NIC." while trying to set a custom profile using WlanSetProfile API.

I can connect to my AP using the Client Utility Application provided by the Atheros. I cannot figure out what might be the cause of this message. Can any one suggest?

Thank you in advance & sorry for my English.